# Mockito ArgumentCaptor equivalent in spockframework

Tags: groovy, spock

I'm beginning to write unit tests with spockframework, and I want to verify the arguments passed to some method of a class my test depends on. In Mockito we have ArgumentCaptor to do this, but I  couldn't figure out a way to do that on spock.

Maybe some manipulation on the closure (I'm still trying to learn that)?
Or spock have some built in functionality?

I appreciate any guidance to learn that!

Comment: You asked for guidance to learn: Spock has a very good [manual](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/index.html), give it a try. I recommend to fully read it which you should be able to do in a few hours. Afterwards you don't remember **how** to do everything in detail, of course. But you will know **what** is possible and when you need it you can search the manual for it. My old chemistry teacher used to say: "Knowledge means to know where to find it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it in Spock:

```
def "it checks the arguments passed to the helper"() {
    given:
    def cut =new Cut(helper:Mock(Helper))

    when:
    cut.doStuff()

    then:
    1 * cut.helper(expectedArg) >> returnedResult

    where:
    expectedArg="This is expected"
    returnedResult="xyz"
}
```